# Partially submitting a form for the purpose of "sequentially" asking for input

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have a JSF page where users can enter their car into my database. The form has three input fields:

- Manufacturer
- Model
- Registration

I am using PrimeFaces 3.0.M2 and both the `Manufacturer` and `Model` field are autocomplete input fields:

```
<p:autoComplete id="manufacturer"
                minQueryLength="3"
                completeMethod="#{carController.completeManufacturer}"
                forceSelection="true"
                value="#{carController.manufacturer}" />
```

The field for the model looks the same, with slightly different values obviously.

The managed bean looks as follows (slightly abbreviated):

```
private String manufacturer;
private String model;
private String registration;

public List<String> completeManufacturer(String query) {
    List<String> ms = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Manufacturer m : manufacturerFacade.findAllByName(query)) {
        ms.add(m.getLongName());
    }
    return ms;
}

public List<String> completeModel(String query) {
    List<String> ms = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Model m :
            modelFacade.findAllByManufacturer(manufacturerFacade.findByName(manufacturer))) {
        ms.add(m.getShortName());
    }
    return ms;
}
```

The problem lies in completing the `model` field. I need this field to only display autocompletion results based on the selected manufacturer, but the `manufacturer` String in the managed bean does not get populated until the entire form is submitted, so I cannot look the models up that are associated with the selected manufacturer.

How would I go about submitting only the `manufacturer` field, without submitting the entire form, so I can look the models of the selected manufacturer up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a selectListener, like so:

```
<p:autoComplete id="manufacturer"
                minQueryLength="3"
                completeMethod="#{carController.completeManufacturer}"
                forceSelection="true"
                selectListener="#{carController.manufacturerSelected}"
                value="#{carController.manufacturer}" />
```

and then in the controller:

```
public void manufacturerSelected(SelectEvent vce) {
    String nameOfSelected = vce.getObject().toString();
    // whatever logic comes to your mind
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick! I was not aware you could pull the input from the text field using the SelectEvent. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could add an extra ajax handler to the manafucturer input field and then handle the `onchange` event. In the server-side handler, simply remember the new value in your backing bean.

If you then put your backing bean in the view scope, the ajax requests originating from the model input field will get the same instance and you have direct access to the manufacturer field that you previously remembered.